# When trying to restore the data on a partition to a different partition, will the first partition be written?

Tags: data-recovery

I am new to data recovery software. Many have a scan step and next a restore step, like Recuva.

After scanning a partition for recoverable files on it, in the restore step, many allow to write the recoverable data to a different partition than the partition being just scanned. I wonder when restoring to a different partition, whether the scanned partition will be written? I learned that never modify data on a partition if planning to recover its previous data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason for the recovery program to write to the source volume. Unless the developers are brain-dead or the program is buggy, and as long as you pay attention to the options and locations you use in the program, then you will be safe. You can mitigate the issues with bad recovery programs by avoiding new programs or beta versions and sticking with ones that have been around for a while and have positive reviews.